# Intellisense doesn't work in Code-Blocks in Ubuntu 16.04 for C++ standard library functions

Tags: c++, ubuntu, stl, codeblocks

In codeblocks of Windows OS, I declare a Standard Template Library(STL) in C++ like this:

```
queue<int>Q;
```

Then if I write this Q with dot(.), a lot of functions' recommendations were shown that the Q has. But when I installed codeblocks in Ubuntu these types of recommendations of STL are not showing.

Why doesn't this work with the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @user0042 Isn't intellisense a VS-specific thing?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's called that on any IDE's I think. They invented that specific term maybe. I believe the question is more understandable for a broader mass changing the term.

Comment: @user0042 Not sure, I've not seen it being used with this meaning. Other names for those things are 'autocompletion' or '[code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion)'.